# JSF2 h:message is not displayed in its specific field

Tags: jsf, javabeans, message

I want to display messages next to h:inputText fields but they just won't show there but are displayed in a field for global messages instead.

The message fields are bound to a inputText by a binding tag but when i call them with getClientId() in my backing bean the returned id seems to be wrong. I think this causes the messages to be displayed in a global field.

This can be viewed in the linked image below.

[image: Display of the website]

My page:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="editPanel">
        <a4j:queue requestDelay="300" ignoreDupResponses="true" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Kostenstelle</td>
                <td><h:inputText id="kst" inputType="text" placeholder=""
                        value="#{kostenstellenBean.kst}" label="Kostenstelle"
                        maxlength="5" binding="#{kostenstellenBean.kstInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonPanel kstMessage" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
                <td><h:message id="kstMessage" for="kst" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bezeichnung</td>
                <td><h:inputText id="bezeichnung" inputType="text"
                        placeholder="" value="#{kostenstellenBean.bezeichnung}"
                        label="Bezeichnung" maxlength="20"
                        binding="#{kostenstellenBean.bezeichnungInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonPanel bezeichnungMessage" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
                <td><h:message id="bezeichnungMessage" for="bezeichnung" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BA</td>
                <td><h:inputText id="ba" inputType="text" placeholder=""
                        value="#{kostenstellenBean.ba}" label="BA" maxlength="3"
                        binding="#{kostenstellenBean.baInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonPanel baMessage" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
                <td><h:message id="baMessage" for="ba" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BK</td>
                <td><h:inputText id="bk" inputType="text" placeholder=""
                        value="#{kostenstellenBean.bk}" label="BK" maxlength="3"
                        binding="#{kostenstellenBean.bkInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonPanel bkMessage" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
                <td><h:message id="bkMessage" for="bk" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>BL</td>
                <td><h:inputText id="bl" inputType="text" placeholder=""
                        value="#{kostenstellenBean.bl}" label="BL" maxlength="3"
                        binding="#{kostenstellenBean.blInput}">
                        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="buttonPanel blMessage" />
                    </h:inputText></td>
                <td><h:message id="blMessage" for="bl" /></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 
            <h:inputHidden id="index" inputType="text" placeholder=""
                value="#{kostenstellenBean.index}" label="Index" />
            <h:inputHidden id="row" inputType="boolean" placeholder=""
                value="#{kostenstellenBean.rowSelected}" label="Index" />
                 -->
        </table>
        <rich:panel id="buttonPanel">
            <bwf:commandButton id="save" value="Speichern"
                disabled="#{!kostenstellenBean.validateData()}">
                <rich:componentControl target="confirmation_save" operation="show" />
            </bwf:commandButton>
            <bwf:commandButton id="edit" value="Ändern"
                disabled="#{!kostenstellenBean.rowSelected or !kostenstellenBean.validData}">
                <rich:componentControl target="confirmation_edit" operation="show" />
            </bwf:commandButton>
            <bwf:commandButton id="delete" value="Löschen"
                disabled="#{!kostenstellenBean.rowSelected}">
                <rich:componentControl target="confirmation_delete"
                    operation="show" />
            </bwf:commandButton>
            <h:messages />
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

And my validation method in the backing bean:

```
public boolean validateData() {
    boolean valid = true;
    String message;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (kst == 0) {
        message = "Kostenstelle ungültig! ";
        context.addMessage(kstInput.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(message
                + kstInput.getClientId()));
        valid = false;
    }
    if (bezeichnung == null || bezeichnung.isEmpty()) {
        message = "Bezeichnung muss vorhanden sein!";
        context.addMessage(bezeichnungInput.getClientId(),
                new FacesMessage(message));
        valid = false;
    }
    if (ba + bk + bl != 100) {
        message = "Die Summe aller Verteilungsschlüssel muss 100 ergeben! ";
        context.addMessage(baInput.getClientId(), new FacesMessage(message));
        valid = false;
    }
    validData = valid;
    return valid;
}
```

All those input fields change the command buttons availability depending on their input. If it is not valid, the command buttons should be disabled. This works so far.

The problem is that the messages invoked in the backing bean are not displayed next to the input fields which I address by their binding and `getClientId()` but in the field for global messages under the command buttons (This field should be removed when all messages are displayed properly.).

Hopefully someone could point out a mistake I made or tell me the flaws in my logic.

Comment: what are the clientID's in the faces messages? Are they the real full correct client id's?

Comment: When I add them to the messages like this: 
new FacesMessage(message + bezeichnungInput.getClientId()) 
it says they translate to form:kst, form:bezeichnung or form:ba even though the only tags surrounding the a4j:outputPanel are ui:composition and html:body.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by trying a different approach.

Now I'm using the required attribute for the first two input fields which simply should not be empty, resulting in the error messages being displayed in the specified message fields.

For the other three input fields a method in the backing bean checks if their sum equals 100 and if not just displays a global message.